# Sending ^] in a nested telnet session

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, telnet

Following is the sequence:

- Telnet from a terminal session to a remote linux machine, Call it A.
- Telnet to some device, Say B, that is accessible only from A.

Now, How do I quit the telnet session to B and stay live on A?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the *inetutils* version of telnet client, you can use the `send escape` command:

```
a$ telnet b
  b$ telnet c
    c$ ^]
telnet> send escape
  telnet> q
  b$
```

Or use the logout/disconnect command of C:

```
a$ telnet b
  b$ telnet c
    c$ exit
  b$
```

And stop using telnet, damn it.

Comment: the first solution worked for me,... and I can not use logout or exit because c is not a linux machine, its an embedded box...

Answer (score 1):

Could you use a different escape sequence when logging in to either A or B? For example,

```
telnet -e ^Q A
telnet B
```

gives you ^Q on A and ^[ on B.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, But the problem is I am not using telnet program directly, but it is being used inside the script that I use to log in to the box... Thanks anyways...

Comment: You should be able to change the escape character from the escape mode as well: press ^], tell telnet to `set escape ^Q` (or whetever) and carry on.